# Reuse dynamic views within a ListView item

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

In Android, the `ListView` and `RecyclerView` reuses view objects when the user scrolls to improve efficiency by not inflating / creating the view objects over and over again.

This is straight forward for any simple lists, but my use case is a bit different. Each item in the list has another list of other items, you can think of it as a list of posts and each post has a list of tags. It can be visualized as follows:

```
-------------
Post 1
<Tag1> <Tag2> <Tag3>
-------------
Post 2
<Tag4>
-------------
Post 3
<Tag5> <Tag6>
-------------
```

Since each post has a variable number of tags, it is not as trivial if we want to reuse a set tag view objects across different ListView item.

My current approach to this problem is that there is an implementation of `ReusableViewPool` which acts as a pool of reusable tag view objects in the above case where each ListView item can get view object from the pool and return unused view object back to the pool. The interface is like:

```
public interface ReusableViewPool {
    View get();
    void recycle(View v);
}
```

In the `ListAdapter` or `RecyclerView.Adapter`, it works like:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // return extra tag views to the pool
    // add missing tag views from the pool
    // update the tag views
}
```

The approach works fine, but I think this is quite troublesome for a common problem.

So the question is, what approach will you guys take to solve the problem? Do you have any elegant solution in mind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this technique in the past, I think it's a valid design.

In your case, I might consider a different approach: having a single `TextView` and making a single `SpannableString` containing all the tag names, marked up to give the proper look.  A lot of it depends on your implementation, though:

1. Layout/Overflow -- does the tag section have a sort of flow layout or do you have a horizontal scroll to keep all the tags on a single line?
2. Graphics -- do you have icons interspersed between the names?  Do they have different colors or shapes depending on the tag type?
3. Typography -- do the tag names have different styles or colors depending on the tag type?

If you update your question with some details and preferable some images/screenshots, I can add some sample code.

Comment: Thanks. Using `SpannableString` is a nice idea, which also fits my current use case. But if the child views become more complicated in the future, it may be another story.